# Condicion IF en WHERE de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero saber si existe alguna manera en la que dentro de un `WHERE` si el resultado es `1` que haga tal cosa y si es `0` que haga tal otra. tal cual se comporta un `IF`.

El problema que tengo es que estoy queriendo adjuntar los precios a un documento. Pero uno de los códigos no tiene precio en `price_code = 1`. Por lo tanto me borra la linea del resultado porque no cumple la condición.

Rescatado de los comentarios: Si cuando busco en `price_code = 1` no encuentra un valor entonces debería ir a buscar el Costo en la tabla `costs`, columna `cost_price`.

Dejo un resumen:

[image: ql]

Script SQL:

```
SQL
SELECT  a.item_code, a.trx_type, a.trx_num, a.qty, b.list_price
FROM moves AS a
INNER JOIN items_price AS b
ON a.item_code = b.item_code
INNER JOIN costs AS c
ON a.item_code = c.item_code
WHERE b.price_code = '1'
ORDER BY a.item_code DESC;
```

Comment: ¿Qué has probado? Poder, se puede. ¿Podrías poner la consulta SQL en un copiar/pegar texto y no como captura de pantalla? Gracias.

Comment: Si claro ya lo hago

Comment: Por cierto, recuerda que `WHERE` debe usarse para limitar los resultados de la consulta, y no para alterar sus valores, por lo que quizá lo que quieres hacer se puede plantear de una manera diferente. Pon algún ejemplo en tu pregunta para entenderte mejor.

Comment: Dada tu propia pregunta,  ¿qué es lo que deseas que haga cuando el valor es 1 y que cuando el valor es 0?

Comment: @OscarGarcia ya esta el ejemplo en el excel que adjunte, La única manera que conozco es la que hice. El resultado que necesito es 1 solo, necesito específicamente lo que esta en el apartado de "Resultado que quiero". Cosas que he probado, bueno cientos, todo lo que he visto por internet de IF, CASE, WHEN, etc.

Comment: @Aprendiz si cuando busco en price_code = 1 no encuentra un valor entonces debería ir a buscar el Costo en la tabla costs, columna cost_price. esta el ejemplo en el excel

Comment: Creo que tenes que reeplantear tu duda.. vos queres price_code = 1 o el menor price_code que haya?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! De paso mira todo eso ;)

Comment: hay solo un resultado para cada item_code no hay menor ni mayor. Lo que quiero es que si un item_code no tiene un valor en price_code = 1 entonces tiene que ir y traerme el costo de la tabla costs , columna cost_price. esta en el excel

Comment: yo tambien soy programador, toda la gente que esta aca tambien lo es, y la ayuda que te proporcionan es gratis y viene de su tiempo. Si te indicamos algo, es para que no estemos perdiendo tiempo tratando de entender tu problema. Existe un case, pero tiene que tener una condicion logica, ya que los querys son matematica pura, y se aplica la condicion campo por campo. se procesan los campos en el orden que pedis y de la forma que pedis. no va a traer un campo condicionalmente por un where, o lo trae o no. Lo que vos queres resolver, por lo que decis, implica o un procedimiento o varios querys.

Comment: Por lo que intentas explicar parece que tu consulta está mal planteada. Si quieres que aparezca un registro aunque no tenga relación en otra tabla debes usar, por ejemplo, `LEFT JOIN` en vez de `INNER JOIN`. En caso de que no exista el registro en esa tabla los valores serán `NULL`, por lo que en tu `WHERE` deberás contemplar esa posibilidad.

Comment: He reproducido tus datos [esta página en línea](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rQVYLpDfLKVa2vw4s61Rcq/0). Como podrás comprobar no coinciden tus ejemplos de la captura de pantalla. Ahora, con el esquema delante y viendo lo que deseas obtener, me he dado cuenta que no tiene ningún sentido lo que quieres. Es decir, sólo hay dos registros con `price_code` a `1`, por lo que sólo puedes tener tres resultados, nunca dos. Además, como no has incluido ese valor en tus ejemplos y tampoco coinciden los datos que se muestran con los que hay en las tablas, ***es imposible entender qué quieres conseguir***.

Comment: Leyendo los comentarios he entendido mejor lo que quieres hacer, aunque en el ejemplo siguen sin ser coherentes los datos que muestras. He editado la pregunta agregando la nueva información que aportas en los comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entendí con tu explicación lo que necesitas es mostrar los datos de la tabla `moves` y la columna `list_price` de la tabla `items_price` si `price_code` es 1, si es 2 en su lugar mostrar la columna `cost_price` de la tabla `costs`, algo así?

```
item_code  |  trx_type  |  trx_num  |  qty  |  SI price_code = 1 MOSTRAR list_price SINO cost_price
```

Si es así prueba con esto:

```
SELECT
    moves.item_code,
    moves.trx_type,
    moves.trx_num,
    moves.qty,
    IFNULL(items_price.list_price, costs.cost_price) AS list_price
FROM moves
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM items_price WHERE price_code = '1'
) AS items_price
    ON items_price.item_code = moves.item_code
INNER JOIN costs
    ON costs.item_code = moves.item_code;
```

Si no es lo que necesitas, arregla tu ejemplo que incluso los `trx_num` no coinciden, así la comunidad puede ayudarte mejor y más rápido.

Answer (score 1):

En la cláusula `WHERE` puedes usar cualquiera de las [funciones de control de flujo](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html), pero creo que no lo necesitas ahí. Mejor haz un `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.item_code
     , a.trx_type
     , a.trx_num
     , a.qty
     , ifnull( b.list_price, c.cost_price )
  FROM moves AS a
    LEFT JOIN items_price AS b
      ON    b.item_code = a.item_code
        AND b.price_code = '1'
    LEFT JOIN costs AS c
      ON c.item_code = a.item_code
  ORDER BY a.item_code DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien tu pregunta, quieres lo siguiente:

- Si existe un registro del artículo en la tabla `items_price` con `items_price.price_code = 1` mostrar el valor de `items_price.list_price`.
- En caso contrario mostrar el valor de `costs.cost_price`.

En ese caso hago uso de `LEFT JOIN` para enlazar tablas llenando con un `NULL` los campos de las tablas enlazadas que no tienen registros asociados.

Al hacerlo así, cuando no exista relación con la tabla `items_price` con la condición dada `items_price.list_price` valdrá `NULL`.

Con un `IF` podemos detectar este caso y mostrar el valor de `costs.cost_price` en ese caso:

```
SELECT
  a.item_code,
  a.trx_type,
  a.trx_num,
  a.qty,
  IF (
    b.list_price IS NULL,
    c.cost_price,
    b.list_price
  ) list_price
FROM moves AS a
LEFT JOIN costs AS c
  ON a.item_code = c.item_code
LEFT JOIN items_price AS b
  ON a.item_code = b.item_code
  AND b.price_code = '1'
ORDER BY a.item_code ASC
```

Tienes un [ejemplo en línea en este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rQVYLpDfLKVa2vw4s61Rcq/1).

Cuando digo que en tu ejemplo están mal los datos, me refiero al caso del artículo `a`: los valores en `items_price.list_price` y `costs.cost_price` son `7`, pero tú pones `4`.